# Colors are messed, text color same as background color and more weird stuff

Tags: windows-explorer, colors, themes

I'm not sure what resulted in this, but currently it's downright impossible to write in a .txt file or see the window options for apps.

like this:

[image: like this]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

or this:

[image: or this]

or this after high contrast:

[image: or this after high contrast]

I don't really remember installing or changing any software before this had happened. It seems to be an error caused by my OS since it affects all apps, I just opened a zip file and background seems to be black, like the text [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLUY.png), I believe it's an error in theme, such that windows colors the background of the text boxes (Or navigation boxes like the photo before) fully black like the text, rendering the text unreadable.

I have tried System file check (SFC) Scan and Repair System Files & DISM to fix things and it says it fixed corrupted files, but it didn't affect the problem

I've created another account to test whether the problem would still be there, and it turns out that it is. I'm not sure if this indicates that the problem is in the internal files of the OS or if it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Please add more information. What things were done to or observed on the computer leading up to this? What are the details of the system? Is this affecting all programs?

Comment: @music2myear added more details